# Android - PHP if else does not halt

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm currently trying to update database using PHP and MySQL in Android.

Here's my code for PHP :

```
<?php

    $slot_name = $_GET['slot_name'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // MySQL select row with matched slotname
    $checkSQL = mysqli_query($db->connect(), "SELECT AVAILABLE_SLOT FROM parking_slot WHERE SLOT_NAME = '$slot_name'");
    $checkResult = mysqli_fetch_object($checkSQL);
    $valueSlot = $result->AVAILABLE_SLOT;

    // MySQL update row with matched slotname
    $updateRow = mysqli_query($db->connect(), "UPDATE parking_slot SET available_slot = available_slot - 1 WHERE slot_name = '$slot_name'");

    $checkFull = "Parking Slot is full! You are not parked!";

    if($valueSlot < 1)
    {
        // Showing that the parking slot is full
        echo $checkFull;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "a";
        $updateRow;
    }

?>
```

Somehow when `$valueSlot` which is the value of `AVAILABLE_SLOT` in my database is less than 1, the functions inside `else` is still executed. So every functions inside `if` and `else` works even when `valueSlot` is less than one which means I'd get negative values for my `AVAILABLE_SLOT` which is illogical -.-

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: `$valueSlot = $result->AVAILABLE_SLOT;` should be `$valueSlot = $checkResult->AVAILABLE_SLOT;` check once.

Comment: Are you expecting `$updateRow` to fire a function? That SQL query is fired the moment `$updateRow` is assigned.

Comment: Wow thanks Anant and Castis, both of your answers enlightened me. I didn't realize that I haven't changed `$result` to `$checkResult` and now I know that a query is fired upon assignment!

Comment: Was editing your answer, because both of your answers are correct combined lol..

Comment: @KevinMurvie as a heads up, sql statements are fired when `mysqli_query()` is called. Check out the section 'Return Values' in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to see what `$updateRow` contains.

Comment: @castis, Thanks! I thought I was assigning it into a variable, like programming in Java or C++.. Oooooooohhh! So that's why there are things like `if($result)` I was wondering does it detect that `$result` was run or whatever that is ahahhaa..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that need to resolve is:-

You are calling `AVAILABLE_SLOT;` on an undefined variable `$result` which is not defined anywhere.

So:-

```
$valueSlot = $result->AVAILABLE_SLOT;
```

should be

```
$valueSlot = $checkResult->AVAILABLE_SLOT;
```

In addition as mentioned by castis, your `$updateRow` is fired when it is assigned, so basically you were calling it everytime you call that php file.